# Way to represent a sequence with multiple numbers in a row?

Tags: sequences-and-series

*I am not familiar with the terminology here, so please bear with me (and feel free to point me elsewhere if there is better reading on this).*

I am coming from a computer science background, and I am trying to model digital waveforms; for example, imagine I have a signal which is on/off at time `t` according to:

```
t(0) = on (1)
t(1) = off (0)
t(2) = off (0)
t(3) = off (0)
t(4) = on (1)
t(5) = off (0)
t(6) = off (0)
t(7) = off (0)
t(8) = on (1)
```

I am trying to model the sequence of times when the signal is on.

If the signal is on for only 1 unit whne it turns on, I know I can model the sequence using a polynomial. For example:

```
Sequence: 0, 4, 8, 12, 16
English: 1 on, 3 off, repeating
Equation: 4x
```

However, I don't know how to model this if the "wave" spans more than one unit when it hits.

```
Sequence: 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 17
English: 2 on, 3 off, repeating
Equation: ???
```

Is there a canonical way to model this? Trivially, I could model this with 2 equations (`4x` and `4x + 1`), but as the wave becomes wider I will need linearly more equations. Can I collapse this into a single equation? (or ideally, a closed-form solution that tells me whether the signal is on / off at time `t`.)

Comment: I suppose I can use a modulo to model this: `t(n) = OFF_WIDTH * Math.floor(n / ON_WIDTH) + (n % ON_WIDTH)` but this doesn't get me closer to knowing if 628723 is on or off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model this using modulo, the signal is on at time $t$ iff $$t\mod 4 \in [0, 1]$$. If you want to phrase it in terms of OFF_WIDTH and ON_WIDTH it would be $$t\mod(\text{OFF_WIDTH}+\text{ON_WIDTH})<\text{ON_WIDTH}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2x-{5+(-1)^x\over2}$$ should give you $0,1,4,5,8,9,\dotsc$ for $x=1,2,3,4,5,6,\dotsc$.

Comment: How does this generalize if the on width is like 4?